# Calculating difference between 2 times, excluding weekends, then averaging the results

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel 2007 worksheet where I need to calculate the difference between 2 times, excluding weekends, then at the end of a week or month, be able to find the average of the amounts of time in the 'difference' column.

Here's what I have so far:

```
=NETWORKDAYS(A3,H3)-1&" DAYS, "&TEXT(H3-A3,"HH"" HRS AND ""MM""MIN"""))
```

Which gives me a result of **1 DAYS, 02 HRS AND 03MIN** which is fine; I just can't figure out a way to find an average of the data in that column with the time expressed in this format.

Any suggestions?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 3):

Your existing formula won't always work, e.g. if A3 is a Thursday at 10:00 and H3 is the following day at 09:00 shouldn't the result be

`0 DAYS, 23 HRS AND 00MIN`

but actual result with that formula is 1 day too high, i.e.

`1 DAYS, 23 HRS AND 00MIN`

Why not return the result in hh:mm and then you can average those, i.e. use this formula

`=NETWORKDAYS(A3,H3)-1+MOD(H3,1)-MOD(A3,1)`

custom format results as [h]:mm then you can simply average the result column

Note: the formula works assuming that A3 and/or H3 are always weekdays

**Alternative solution:**

Use this formula to fix the problem I identified

`=NETWORKDAYS(A3,H3)-1-(MOD(H3,1)< MOD(A3,1))&" DAYS, "&TEXT(H3-A3,"HH"" HRS AND ""MM"" MIN""")`

Assuming you have results using that formula in J3:J10 try this formula to give you an average in the same format

`=SUMPRODUCT(MID(0&J3:J10,FIND({"D","H","M"},J3:J10)-2,3)/{1,24,1440})/ROWS(J3:J10)`

format result cell as custom:

`d" DAYS, "hh" HRS AND "mm" MIN"`

Note: this works assuming that no period is longer than 99 working days and where average working days is < 32 days

Comment: I'm quite new to using Excel and its formulas, but doesn't the **-1** in my original formula address the problem of the result being 1 day too high?

Comment: Also, formatting the result as [h]:mm completely removes the _days_ portion of the result - it just completely ignores the days. I wouldn't mind if the result is expressed as hours and minutes as long as it also included 24 hours for every day also.

Comment: No because you will get the same number of days whether the time gap is 23:00 hours or 25:00 - I'll post a working version in my answer. To get hours over 24 you need to include the square brackets like [h]:mm not h:mm

Comment: @Jill, to see what's wrong with your existing formula, put in 9/26/13 11:00pm and 9/27/2013 01:am. You should get 0 days and 2 hours, but instead you get 1 day and 2 hours, because `=NETWORKDAYS()` counts any portion of a workday as a full day.

Comment: Ah! Thank you for the bracket help - that made all the difference in the world. I now get a result that includes the days. Thank you for working on posting a version that will work for me to get the correct number of days. Also, in answer to one of your comments above, we will not be entering any date information on weekends.

Comment: @Dane - Thank you... Now I see the problem. I didn't realize that NETWORKDAYS counted any portion of a day as a full day. Is there a formula that would work properly and still exclude Saturday and Sunday?

Comment: I posted a version that will always give the correct days - see my edited answer

Comment: @Jill, barry houdini's new "Alternative Solution" will correct for the odd behavior of `=NETWORKDAYS()`. You really probably need to do two columns, one using the pretty format that includes the text, and another that just has a simple time value in it. Use the simple time value for your average.

Comment: I also included a way to get an average from the text results assuming you use my suggested formula

Comment: .....also I'm not sure I would say `"NETWORKDAYS counts any portion of a workday as a full day"` - it simply ignores the times and uses the dates only

Comment: Thank you so much Barry and Dane for your help. This works perfectly!